# OpenCV 4 | no module name cv2.cv2 |

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and I installed OpenCV 4 using `pip` but I get the following error message:

> no module name cv2.cv2

`sudo apt-get install python-opencv` installs an older version so it's also not useful to me.

Is there any way or solution to install OpenCV4 on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed OpenCV 4 on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ multiple times following these instructions.  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/

The instructions are too long to paste in this answer and it is not my work.  In summary you need to compile OpenCV yourself. This takes awhile on the Pi but if you follow the instructions exactly it works.

That website also has a lot of good tutorials about OpenCV.